# Closures under different inner products and the injectivity

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I'm interested in the following scenario.  I have a dense subset $M$ of a Hilbert space $H$, and I want to complete $M$ in two different ways with respect to the inner products
$$
\langle x,y\rangle_L = \langle L x, Ly\rangle_H
$$
where $L$ is a positive definite self adjoint, densely defined operator on $H$.  Analogously, I have an inner product $\langle x,y\rangle_T$ for some operator $T$ with the same properties.  Now assume that
$$
\|x\|_L \leq C \|x\|_T
$$
for $x\in M = D(A)\cap D(T)$ (this is how I actually define $M$).  I would like to conclude that the inclusion map, $I:H_T\to H_L$ is injective, and that's where I'm stuck.

I have seen posts on here that the issue is the ''closability'' fo the quadratic forms or, alternatively, $L$ and $T$ are closable operators.  I would like to understand how to deduce injectivity from this closability property.

Comment: Regardless of algebraic or topological structures, inclusion maps are always injective by definition. Does this answer your question?

Comment: No, it does not.  Suppose I look at the completion of smooth functions in both $L^\infty$ and $W^{1,\infty}$ norms.  It is easy to construct sequences which converge to zero in $L^\infty$, but have nonzero limit in $W^{1,\infty}$, giving the inclusion map $W^{1,\infty}\to L^\infty$ a kernel.  There is something gained in the Hilbert space version I am posing, and I want to understand that.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Sobolev spaces, so I'm not the person to ask, but I don't understand how this could work. If $I : W^{1,\infty} \to L^\infty$ is the inclusion map, then as I understand the terms, $I(f) = f$ for all $f \in W^{1, \infty}$. Thus, $I(f) = I(g) \implies f = I(f) = I(g) = g \implies f = g$. Or, if you like, if $I(f) = 0$, then $f = I(f) = 0$, so the kernel is trivial. I must be misunderstanding the idea of the inclusion map or injectivity in this context. It seems worth clarifying these terms to me, but again, I'm not really your target audience.

Comment: So perhaps this needs to be clarified: my inclusion map is original posed on the dense subset where it is injective.  Then it is extended to the closure in the natural way (I.e. the map on a limit point is the limit of the map on the sequence).  It is this closure of the inclusion map that can have this degeneracy.